# split a string from a list in a Pandas series

Tags: pandas, dataframe, series

I have a series of geographic coordinates as below and am fairly new to Series.  I need to extract the latitude and longitude from these coordinates into separate series to concatenate back into the dataframe.    I have tried a few different methods w/o luck.  Can someone please help me understand how best to do this?

Code I have tried:

### printing type of this is a `<list>` but just returns the first record in the series

```
df['Location'].str.split(',')[0]
```

### treat as string and try to extract the first list element and then the first of the tuple

```
longitude = df['Location'].str[0][0].replace('(', '')
```

The Location field is a series of lists of tuples.

```
0         [(34.0255,  -118.3002)]
1         [(34.0256,  -118.3089)]
2         [(34.0738,  -118.2078)]
3         [(34.0492,  -118.2391)]
4         [(34.0108,  -118.3182)]
                   ...
594800    [(34.0436,  -118.3053)]
594801    [(33.9572,  -118.3962)]
594802    [(34.1684,  -118.3982)]
594803    [(34.1976,  -118.3965)]
594804    [(34.0504,  -118.3442)]
```

Comment: post `df['Location'].head(5).to_dict()` for testing

Comment: {0: '(34.0255, -118.3002)', 1: '(34.0256, -118.3089)', 2: '(34.0738, -118.2078)', 3: '(34.0492, -118.2391)', 4: '(34.0108, -118.3182)'}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the data from the comment, `Location` is actually a string, containing a tuple. And there's a None among the values.

So we need to parse the coordinates and be careful of Nones.

I have tried two approaches

1. Using `ast.literal_eval` to parse a tuple from a string. [Convert a String representation of a Dictionary to a dictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/988228/convert-a-string-representation-of-a-dictionary-to-a-dictionary)

```
import ast

def get_coordinate_ast(location, coord_idx):
    try:
        return ast.literal_eval(location)[coord_idx]
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        return
```

```
%%time
# getting lat
df["lat_ast"] = df["Location"].apply(lambda l: get_coordinate_ast(l, 0))
# getting long
df["lon_ast"] = df["Location"].apply(lambda l: get_coordinate_ast(l, 1))

print(f"Not able to parse lat: {df['lat_ast'].isna().sum()}")
print(f"Not able to parse lon: {df['lon_ast'].isna().sum()}")
```

Output:

```
malformed node or string: nan
malformed node or string: nan
Not able to parse lat: 1
Not able to parse lon: 1
CPU times: user 6.41 s, sys: 57.5 ms, total: 6.47 s
Wall time: 6.48 s
```

2. Using regexp:

```
%%time
# getting lat
df["lat_re"] = df["Location"].apply(lambda l: get_coordinate_re(l, 0))
# getting long
df["lon_re"] = df["Location"].apply(lambda l: get_coordinate_re(l, 1))

print(f"Not able to parse lat: {df['lat_re'].isna().sum()}")
print(f"Not able to parse lon: {df['lon_re'].isna().sum()}")
```

Output:

```
expected string or bytes-like object
expected string or bytes-like object
Not able to parse lat: 1
Not able to parse lon: 1
CPU times: user 941 ms, sys: 16.8 ms, total: 958 ms
Wall time: 960 ms
```

Both methods produce only 1 unparsed value (last row).
And give equal results

```
print((df["lat_ast"] != df["lat_re"]).sum())
print((df["lon_ast"] != df["lon_re"]).sum())
```

Output:

```
1
1
```

(These are both Nones, that didn't match)

However, `re` method is much more quicker: `960 ms` vs `6.48 s`.

Comment: I get an index error which is likely because the data is not exactly as i described it.  The data is from here:   https://data.lacity.org/Public-Safety/Traffic-Collision-Data-from-2010-to-Present/d5tf-ez2w - see export in top left.  From there, I loaded a data frame with df = pd.read_csv('../data/Traffic_Collision_Data_from_2010_to_Present.csv') and then try to manipulate the Location field.

Comment: I have just rewritten the answer to deal with the new info.

Comment: For completeness and my understanding, what is the function get_coordinate_re(location, index).  Thank you

Comment: I created a function to naively parse the location value - that now represents as a string

def get_lat_lon(location, index):
 
    try:
        lat_lon = location.split(',')
        if index == 0:
            return lat_lon[0].replace('(', '')
        elif index == 1:
            return lat_lon[1].replace(')', '')
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        return 0

Answer (score 0):

Construct a new dataframe from records:

```
pd.DataFrame.from_records(df['Location'].apply(pd.Series)[0].values, 
                          columns=['lat', 'long'])
```

---

```
       lat      long
0  34.0255 -118.3002
1  34.0256 -118.3089
2  34.0738 -118.2078
3  34.0492 -118.2391
4  34.0108 -118.3182
```

Comment: I ran this and got this error:  AssertionError: 2 columns passed, passed data had 20 columns - please see comment to Maria K's solution, my full dataset has 20 columns.  Thank you!

Comment: @Cord, so how are you asserting that?